# how to specify Meteor requirements?

Tags: meteor

what is the convention for specifying meteor requirements?  if for example I want to add to a github repository. for other to easily deploy.
some thing like python requirements.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements are located in the `.meteor/` directory in the `packages` file.  Simply add the `.meteor/` directory to your git repository and the requirements will automatically be downloaded when the user runs meteor.

Comment: ok, just thought it would be to much to put `.meteor` in the repo